# Rails problem : sqlite3.h is missing and so more?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, msys2

I am trying to deploy a Rails at Windows 7 32 bits. And here is my Rais version when I checked by `rails -v` : Rails 6.0.3.2

When I tried to make a new rails, I got so many errors. Here is the error I got

[image]

I checked from internet and got that maybe my msys2 had something wrong as they said here https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-05-17-32-bit-msys2-no-longer-actively-supported

I followed him and got no error when installed msys2, but when I downloaded sqlite3.h and tried to installed it, there was still error `mingw32: key ....`

I am very confusing with this error. Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQLite to install it's gem. Go to https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and install the version suitable for your OS. After that retry `bundle install`

If you pay attention your console is telling you to do this already:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But when I download sqlite from that website and install it as it tutorial, I still got the error `mingw32: key ...`, so I am very confusing with that error. Could you please give me some more ?